# Do I get [?] boxes picked up by my local co-op partner?

Tags: lost-planet-2

I played through a lot of Lost Planet 2 with my brother locally, since I can't do online play, but now that I've beaten the game, I'm looking to 'train up' and try to get some better abilities and weapons for when we (hopefully) get high-speed internet next week.

I assume that in online play whoever picks up the [?] box gets the credits in it, but in local multiplayer, P2 doesn't have an account, he just uses my stuff. Right now, we usually get about the same amount, so if I'm losing half of my credits, I'd like to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this today. I didn't pick up any [?] boxes, and my brother picked up about fourteen. I still ended up getting around two to three thousand credits though, so apparently they do count for both. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was of the opinion that each player was allowed to grab the same [?] box.  When I played through it online (other players in the same room), we both could grab the same set of credit boxes.  When I picked it up on my screen, it remained in place on theirs, and vice versa.  Oddly enough, they often weren't even in the same place, which leads me to believe that it is managed on client side.  A local co-op game has a single client, so it is possible that you are losing creds when he picks them up.

Apparently chapter 5-3 is the [best place to farm creds](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_yTEYmgk2Is).

Comment: No, only one of us can pick them up. We usually split up to pick up large amounts, but I'm wondering whether it'd be better for just me to grab them.

Comment: @Ullallulloo: If that's the case, I would reccomend you picking them all up... If you are cred farming.  I played through the entire game the first time without ever using any creds, so it is not necessary if your brother is just joining in to play through the game.  Good luck!

Comment: We've both finished the game, but it's still fun. I guess I'll try to do a test today to find out.